# Compiling CUPS for android x86

Tags: android, linux-kernel, cups, android-x86

I am working on compiling a custom android-x86 build for an embedded device. I need to utilize a USB thermal printer. On Ubuntu it works out of the box with cups on /dev/usb/lp0. I can't seem to find anything regarding instructions on porting CUPS to android-x86 build and I'm not super familiar with this yet. Does anyone have a solution to either compiling CUPS with android-x86 or communicating with /dev/usb/lp0 in android-x86?

Answer (score 1):

CUPS has been 'ported' to Android now (see https://github.com/pelya/android-print-plugin-cups). It's not actually a port, but it installs Debian inside your app's sandbox and sets up CUPS there. Possibly a more maintainable solution since Debian CUPS is stable.

You then obviously need a CUPS driver for your printer, and a way to get it to communicate over USB (libusb). I'm working on this right now for a project and will edit this post when it's fully functional.